# ATOM date format to UNIX in PHP

Tags: php, date, unix, time, atom-feed

I need a feed date/time converted into a unix timestamp in PHP.

from `2010-04-13T10:00:00.000-04:00` -> Unix

I have been trying all sorts of weird things with `date()` and `strtotime()` with no luck.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what problem is being experienced? strtotime should not see the specified date as problematic.  What have you tried and what wrong result did it give to you?

Answer (score 2):

```
$dt=new DateTime("2010-04-13T10:00:00.000-04:00");
echo $dt->format('U');
```

Comment: $feedTime = '2010-04-14T08:30:00.000-04:00';
strtotime($feedTime);

This actually works fine. My problem was my time zone, the above entry resulted in my "hour" being 5 instead of 8, fixed by:

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

This if for a Google Calendar, now that those two timezones are synced there shouldn't be problems. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$time = strtotime(preg_replace('/(T|\.\d{3})/', ' ', '2010-04-13T10:00:00.000-04:00'));
```

Here I used `preg_replace` to replace the `T` and the milliseconds with single spaces.